# Given a C# ArcMap custom toolbar with engine source files in a folder is there a way to install the toolbar and engine without going through VS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, c#, visual-studio, toolbar

I was given ArcMap toolbar and tool engine files without instructions on how to install but the code was done by someone else and it should work. How do I install it in ArcMap 10? I attempted to add the tool by going to customize->toolbar->customize->new and add files, but it wouldn't take the dll files in my directory. Is there another file type it is supposed to take? Or do I need to go through some kind of workaround in VS? I haven't installed ArcMap dev on my version of VS.

Comment: Try adding the .tlb file if there is one. Otherwise, use [ESRIRegAsm](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004n6000000).

Comment: ok, so I was able to add the tlb file and it gave me an added a list of stuff successfully message, but no icons are coming up, and no text as well. I think I'm supposed to add the GUI details somehow?

Comment: They will not pop up automatically. Instead use the Customize-Toolbar menu to toggle Toolbars or use the [Customize dialog](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00v00000000z000000) to add toolbars or commands. Commands will show up in various categories or you can search for them by name.

Comment: right well I forgot to add that I had the checkbox toggled for the tool, but the tlb file I added was from the toolbar tlb file, do I need to configure that with the engine folder? Because where the tool is supposed to be, it is a blank space with no listeners. I actually tried to use the ESRIRegAsm, but I'm not sure what the assembly path would be or where the native com server dll is.

Comment: I tried the Customize dialog, but the tools that were supposed to be part of the toolbar were not visible.

Comment: Was it built against the ArcObjects 10 API? It doesn't always seem necessary, but I think ESRI wants you to re-compile extensions / add-ins for each new version of their software.

Comment: yes, well some components use the API. I looked around and apparently you're supposed to delete an mxt file related to the mxd file you are using the toolbar with in order to save your toolbar settings, but my toolbar doesn't come up to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I developed a toolbar in C# I always install trough DOS using the command lines window (it is in accesories file), and it always works.. you must only consider to use the command window as Administrator this is important...